# Convergence of a sequence of functions?

Tags: real-analysis

Let $(f_n)$ be a sequence of functions such that $f_n(x) \rightarrow 0$ for each $x \in [0,n]$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$. I'm trying to prove or disprove that $\sup_{x \in [0,n]} f_n(x) \rightarrow 0$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Consider $f_n(x)=0$, $x\ne1/n$; $f_n(1/n)=1$.

Answer (score 1):

I find for these sorts of questions it's easier to think graphically $f_{n}(x)=0$ for $x$ not equal to $n$ and $f_{n}(n)=1$. Then the sup is always 1 so the claim is not true.

Answer (score 1):

Both examples don't serve. From the assumptions, $f_n(1/n)$ or $f_n(n)$ must converge to zero and so it cannot be constant.